# Unable to import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, navigationview

I want to have navigation drawer in my application so I am following a tutorial [here](http://desarrollador-android.com/material-design/desarrollo-material-design/pautas-desarrollo/navigation-drawer-android-design-support-library-desarrollo/), 
in which he has imported the `NavigationView` library within his project. When I import that library, an error pops up: 'can not resolve'. So again when I hover over the `import` statement and select 'find jar on web', a message shows saying 'no such library found'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am also facing the same problem and i found a solution by adding the following code to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I also adjusted my targetSdk in the build.gradle file to 22 and i was able to succesfully import the NavigationView without any problem.

Comment: Brilliant! Now it is `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'` with a very recent version.

Comment: Where do you enter this in Visual Studio (Xamarin Android)?

Answer (score 4):

before importing support library, Make sure you have downloaded Android Support Repository using SDK Manager.

Comment: In my version of Android Studio 2.1.2+ you get the problems described in 0:Messages window with hyper-link. Clicking on it should bring you to automated download and install dialog. Just confirm and let the IDE install missing packages for you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have this error with compile design:22 or higher just restart your Android Studio.

Comment: Migrated my code to my new computer. After the initial gradle build the imports from the design library. After a restart of Android studio everything was as inteded.

Answer (score 0):

If in your app `build.gradle` file `compileSdkVersion` reads as say `28`,
then add the following line under dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   --other dependencies
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 }
```

Change the version number according to your `compiledSdkVersion`

Then re-build your project. This brings in the required dependency.